# Get index of current item in a PowerShell loop

Tags: powershell

Given a list of items in PowerShell, how do I find the index of the current item from within a loop?

For example:

```
$letters = { 'A', 'B', 'C' }

$letters | % {
  # Can I easily get the index of $_ here?
}
```

The goal of all of this is that I want to output a collection using [Format-Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Format-Table) and add an initial column with the index of the current item. This way people can interactively choose an item to select.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I am not sure it's possible with an "automatic" variable. You can always declare one for yourself and increment it:

```
$letters = { 'A', 'B', 'C' }
$letters | % {$counter = 0}{...;$counter++}
```

Or use a `for` loop instead...

```
for ($counter=0; $counter -lt $letters.Length; $counter++){...}
```

Comment: Example: `> "A,B,C,D,E,F,G" -split "," | % { $i = 0 } { if ( $i -gt 3 ) { $_ }; ++$i }` Output: `E F G`

Comment: It worked like a charm when I had to rename files with a counter~ `dir | % {$i = 46}{ move-item $_ ("ARM-{0:00000}.pdf" -f $i++)}`

Comment: The `$letters | % {$counter...` option is safe even if `$letters` is only one object and not an array where as the `for` option doesn't handle that properly.

Comment: Thanks for this - I'd never seen that syntax with two sets of curly braces following foreach. It solved the problem of matching up two arrays like this: 
`$selected = $true,$false,$true; @('first','second','third') | % {$i=0}{If($selected[$i]){$_};$i++ } ` to return 'first' and 'third'

Comment: So the trick here is to use `%{} {}` right? What does the first bracket do? And second? Where can I read on it? Thanks

Comment: It's a "shortcut" for foreach-object -Begin {first block} -Process {second block}. The first block is run once before processing, the second is run for each item to process. see get-help foreach-item -full for more info

Answer (score 79):

.NET has some handy utility methods for this sort of thing in System.Array:

```
PS> $a = 'a','b','c'
PS> [array]::IndexOf($a, 'b')
1
PS> [array]::IndexOf($a, 'c')
2
```

Good points on the above approach in the comments. Besides "just" finding an index of an item in an array, given the context of the problem, this is probably more suitable:

```
$letters = { 'A', 'B', 'C' }
$letters | % {$i=0} {"Value:$_ Index:$i"; $i++}
```

Foreach (%) can have a Begin sciptblock that executes once.  We set an index variable there and then we can reference it in the process scripblock where it gets incremented before exiting the scriptblock.

Comment: Also you probably don't want to look up each index of an array item while iterating those items. That'd be linear search for every item; sounds like making one iteration O(n^2) :-)

Comment: `IndexOf` works if your sure you always have an array but the `$letters | % {$i=0}...` method is safe even if `$letters` ends up being only one object and not an array.

Answer (score 60):

For PowerShell 3.0 and later, there is one built in :)

```
foreach ($item in $array) {
    $array.IndexOf($item)
}
```

Comment: This is finding the index of the first item matching every item in the array, not iterating with an index value. This is slower, and if the array contains duplicate items you will get the wrong indexes.

Answer (score 16):

```
0..($letters.count-1) | foreach { "Value: {0}, Index: {1}" -f $letters[$_],$_}
```

Comment: This is clean enough, but it's too bad there's no direct method that doesn't involve searching for the index in the array.

Comment: It's too bad Powershell doesn't expose an automatic variable that counts which iteration we're on.

Answer (score 4):

I found [Cédric Rup's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1785546/22194) very helpful but if (like me) you are confused by the '%' syntax/alias, here it is expanded out:

```
$letters = { 'A', 'B', 'C' }
$letters | ForEach-Object -Begin {$counter = 0} -Process {...;$counter++}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use this pattern:

```
$letters | Select @{n="Index";e={$letters.IndexOf($_)}}, Property1, Property2, Property3
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

(PowerShell 7.4.1)

Since I come across this problem a lot, for convenience I have created a function in my PowerShell profile script.

### Example

```
"a", ("b","c"), "d" | %i{ param($i, $e) "Element $i is $e" }
```

Output:

```
Element 0 is a
Element 1 is b c
Element 2 is d
```

### Solution

```
function ConvertTo-ArrayIndexed {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
            Indexed variant of ForEach-Object

        .EXAMPLE
            "a", ("b","c"), "d" | ConvertTo-ArrayIndexed {param($i, $e) "Element $i is $e"}
            Element 0 is a
            Element 1 is b c
            Element 2 is d
        .EXAMPLE
            "a", ("b","c"), "d" | ConvertTo-ArrayIndexed {"Element $($args[0]) is $($args[1])"}
            Element 0 is a
            Element 1 is b c
            Element 2 is d
        .EXAMPLE
            ConvertTo-ArrayIndexed -InputObject "a", ("b","c"), "d" {param($i, $e) "Element $i is $e"}
            Element 0 is a
            Element 1 is b c
            Element 2 is d
        .EXAMPLE
            ConvertTo-ArrayIndexed -InputObject "a", ("b","c"), "d" {"Element $($args[0]) is $($args[1])"}
            Element 0 is a
            Element 1 is b c
            Element 2 is d
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipeline)][Object] $InputObject,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)][ScriptBlock] $Process
    )
    begin {
        $index = 0
    }
    process {
        # determine if `$InputObject` is provided through pipeline,
        # handle `$InputObject` differently to support array typed values.
        if($input){
            . $Process ($index++) $InputObject
        }
        else{
            foreach($io in $InputObject){
                . $Process ($index++) $io
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Together with function aliases:

```
New-Alias -Name %i -Value ConvertTo-ArrayIndexed
New-Alias -Name mapIndexed -Value ConvertTo-ArrayIndexed
```

---

Modify the function and alias as you wish.
I came from a background where I understand such a function as `mapIndexed`, but `%i` is more succinct and it goes well with the existing `%` alias for `ForEach-Object`.

Also note that ["ForEach" is a "reserved verb"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands?view=powershell-7.4#verb-naming-recommendations), but if you don't mind I think an alias named `ForEach-ObjectIndexed` is pretty nice as well.

Answer (score -5):

For those coming here from Google like I did, later versions of Powershell have a `$foreach` automatic variable. You can find the "current" object with `$foreach.Current`

Comment: most people use `$_` for the current object. Also, OP's question was about finding the index of the current object, not the object itself.