# How to print/append row index number on each line in a file in Powershell

Tags: powershell

sapmple.txt as below

```
row1col1||col2||col2||col3
row2col1||col2||col2||col3
row3col1||col2||col2||col3
```

expected

```
0||row1col1||col2||col2||col3
1||row2col1||col2||col2||col3
2||row3col1||col2||col2||col3
```

I coded like

```
get-content "C:\sample.txt" | foreach { "[|][|]" + $_ } | foreach { Index  + $_ } | set-content "C:\sample1.txt"
```

calling the pipe and then respective index, but not working.

Can you please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get index of current item in Powershell loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785474/get-index-of-current-item-in-powershell-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another thought:

```
% { $i = 0 } { "$i||$_" ; $i++ }
```

Answer (score 3):

just like this:

```
$index = 0
Get-Content 'C:\sample.txt' | ForEach-Object { "{0}||{1}" -f $index++, $_ } | Set-Content 'C:\sample1.txt'
```

If want to prepend leading zeroes to your index so also larger numbers will align (in this example all indices will have 4 digits):

```
Get-Content 'C:\sample.txt' | ForEach-Object { "{0}||{1}" -f ($index++).ToString("0000") , $_ } | Set-Content 'C:\sample1.txt'
```

Comment: Simpler: `ForEach-Object { "{0:0000}||{1}" -f $index++, $_ }`

Answer (score 1):

What is `index` in your example? Strings do not have an index property nor does `Get-Content` create one as far as I know.

`Get-Content` already knows line numbers using `ReadCount` so keeping a running index is redundant. It does however start counting at one so a small adjustment would need to be made there to match your desire.

```
Get-Content C:\temp\text.txt | ForEach-Object {"{0}||{1}" -f ($_.ReadCount - 1),$_}
```

We use the format operator `-f` to try and make for easier to edit output string. Simply pipe the output of the `foreach-object` to its desired output.